# PDFClown Extract table How to extract a table from PDF using PDFClown

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfclown

How would extract an Table from a PDF using PDFClown.

I want to take the Table Data and save it to a DB.

I am open to use different framework/package as long it is free

Thanks